# Get Required Fields in each content type associated with given List

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, content-type, sharepoint-rest-api

I have a list - Documents (Actually document library). I have given it two types of content types :- Document(default) & MyDocumentContentType (this is my custom content type)

Now Content Type Document have Title as Required field.
And Content Type MyDocument have a custom col as required field - "MyRequiredField"

Now I want to fetch all the fields for list Documents, which have required property merged from all the content types.

Currently -> I get only Title as Required Field.

I want    -> Title and MyRequiredField both as Required Fields.

I know I can fetch Fields for perticular content type by using `..../ContentTypes(ID)/Fields`.

But it will give me fields for that particular content type.

Currently I have only option is to iterate over all the content types associated with a list and fetch fields for each, and then merge required flag in code.

But it will take 4 ajax calls if I have 3 content types associated with the list.

Comment: Is `MyRequiredField` site column or list column??

Answer (score 0):

You could use [batch rest api](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/make-batch-requests-with-the-rest-apis) to reduce request to server.

Sample body.

```
--batch_e3b6819b-13c3-43bb-85b2-24b14122fed1
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

GET https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/lee/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('MyList')/ContentTypes('0x0100B0B77BE67D2DE8428E911932E5D0BEDD00D1EE82BD76FBE24EA6D917BE2FE7D769')/fields?$filter=Required%20eq%20true HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json;odata=verbose

--batch_e3b6819b-13c3-43bb-85b2-24b14122fed1
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

GET https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/lee/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('MyList')/ContentTypes('0x01007BF91AB7D4095147B10280A02C55C97D')/fields?$filter=Required%20eq%20true HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json;odata=verbose

--batch_e3b6819b-13c3-43bb-85b2-24b14122fed1--
```